# C# Arguments for a specific process, open browser with url

Tags: c#, .net, string, http, arguments

I am writing an application that is supposed to open a certain process on the click of a button. However, the user has the ability to add new buttons. I'm using the following code for the action that occurs that starts the process on button click:

```
        private void StartProcess(string path)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo StartInformation = new ProcessStartInfo();

        StartInformation.FileName = path;

        Process process = Process.Start(StartInformation);

        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    private void ClickFunc(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists(ProgramPath))
        {
            StartProcess(ProgramPath);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Specified path does not exist, please try again.", "Bad File Path Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is, when the user creates a button for a webpage, it opens the browser, then the webpage. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure I fully understand this. Where is `ProgramPath` declared and isntantiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a process to open the browser with a specific `url` you can try this:

```
string url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

But sometimes if you have problems with the path of your browser, it cannot work properly. The function bellow gives you the path of the browser in the machine.

```
public static string GetDefaultBrowserPath()
{
    string urlAssociation = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http";
    string browserPathKey = @"$BROWSER$\shell\open\command";

    RegistryKey userChoiceKey = null;
    string browserPath = “”;

    try
    {
        //Read default browser path from userChoiceLKey
        userChoiceKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(urlAssociation + @"\UserChoice", false);

        //If user choice was not found, try machine default
        if (userChoiceKey == null)
        {
            //Read default browser path from Win XP registry key
            var browserKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"HTTP\shell\open\command", false);

            //If browser path wasn’t found, try Win Vista (and newer) registry key
            if (browserKey == null)
            {
                browserKey =
                Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
                urlAssociation, false);
            }
            var path = CleanifyBrowserPath(browserKey.GetValue(null) as string);
            browserKey.Close();
            return path;
        }
        else
        {
            // user defined browser choice was found
            string progId = (userChoiceKey.GetValue("ProgId").ToString());
            userChoiceKey.Close();

            // now look up the path of the executable
            string concreteBrowserKey = browserPathKey.Replace(“$BROWSER$”, progId);
            var kp = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(concreteBrowserKey, false);
            browserPath = CleanifyBrowserPath(kp.GetValue(null) as string);
            kp.Close();
            return browserPath;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return "";  
    }
}
```

And you can use the path of the browser and the url of website, for sample:

```
string url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(GetDefaultBrowserPath(), url);
```

In the `url` string you can pass the webpage link. It will open the browser with the url.

See more:

http://www.seirer.net/blog/2014/6/10/solved-how-to-open-a-url-in-the-default-browser-in-csharp

Comment: So, using this, I could use the process ID's of the most common web browsers, set up an if or a case statement, and use the URL from the user input as an argument after the browser opens?