# Hyperlink on popup control does not find hyperlinked file

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

For some reason, the following `hyperlink` on a `popup` control is NOT opening the google website. The popup correctly shows the link, but when I click on the link, I get the following error. The link used (`https://www.google.com/`) works fine if I use it directly on a browser. What I may be missing here, and can we make it work?

**Error**:

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
.....
 <Grid>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">text <Run TextDecorations="Underline" MouseEnter="run_MouseEnter">link</Run>
        </TextBlock>
        <Popup Name="popLink" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Mouse" MaxWidth="200" PopupAnimation="Slide" AllowsTransparency = "True">
            <Border BorderBrush="Beige" BorderThickness="2" Background="White">
                <TextBlock Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap"> <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink_Click" NavigateUri="https://www.google.com/">More info</Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
private void run_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    popLink.IsOpen = true;
}

private void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(((Hyperlink)sender).NavigateUri.ToString());
}
```

**UPDATE**:

More details on the error:

[image]

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=System.Diagnostics.Process
  StackTrace:
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
   at WpfApp2.MainWindow.Hyperlink_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\DotNET_Gen\WPF_Core\WpfApp2\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 45
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.ContentElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink.DispatchNavigation(Object sender)
   at System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.ContentElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at WpfApp2.App.Main()
```

Comment: Can you copy the exception details and add this information to the post, please?

Comment: @Jackdaw In response to your request, I've just added an **UPDATE** section.

Comment: Because of this code is running on my computer, I can only suggest that one of the files required to launch a browser can not be found. Unfortunately your `StackTrace` log does not contain any information about what file causes this exception. **1)** Check the system event log. Perhaps it contain more detailed information what causes this fail. **2)** Try to change the default web browser.

Comment: Did you try to play with `UseShellExecute` property?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Your suggestion worked (thank you). I find your suggestion to be better one for `.NET Core` (that I 'm using). You may want to write it as a `response` (maybe, with a one line explanation) so other readers can benefit from it better. And, I will mark it as an `Answer`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issue is actually related to the app not being able to find the location of the default browser (in my case `Chrome`). I discovered the cause of the issue by going through the following posts:

As the saying goes: `Give credit where credit is due`. Hence, the credit goes to the following users:

1. `Felipe Oriani` on his [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30979896/1232087) post on: What to do if your app is unable to find the path of your browser
2. `Ahmad Hindash` on his [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46755247/1232087) post on how to find the location of a browser
3. `Dxiv` on [details on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38678712/1232087) why sometimes you may get the above error.

Based on my reading of the above posts, I was able to resolve the issue as follows:

```
private void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //PLEASE NOTE: You would want to programmatically find the location of you browser as user `Felipe Oriani` did in his above mentioned post. For brevity, I am leaving that part.
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", ((Hyperlink)sender).NavigateUri.ToString());
}
```

**NOTE**: For now, I will not mark my response as an answer because other users may come up with a better solution (and in that case I will mark his/her response as an answer).